# Space between rows of table on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, tabular

I'm building a table in which I want a given row to be highlighted on hover. However, I want the hover space be  shorter than the row's height. 
Picture for preview. This is printscreen of a Sketch file. You can see that the white border is in a certain distance from the hovered space. Is it even possible to create something like this?

[image]

So far, I tried to make the border-spacing larger but then I get the space between the columns too, which is not the desired outcome.

Comment: Please post some relevant code so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```css
tr{
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px;
}

.hover {
  padding : 5px;
  margin : 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.hover:hover {
   background : lightblue;
   color: darkblue;
   
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="hover">Hover me</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="hover">Hover me</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="hover">Hover me</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using: `border-collapse:separate;` with `border-spacing`

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
}
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:hover {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Table rows cant have have margin or padding values nor can they use border-radius or other properties that transform them.

Comment: Master Yoda, this ALMOST worked :) For whatever reason I'm only getting the space above the row.

Here's my code:

'table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }

tbody {
  tr {
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
      background: blue;
    }

    &:hover td:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    &:hover td:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
  }
}'

Comment: The reason for that is that I only have the bottom border that's visible and I want the hover to be evenly distributed between the bottom borders.